# Create a new variable type that extends an object that converts string into float in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application I'm writing a lot of formulas, and it makes it super tricky to debug those formulas because i'm parsing the data from a mixed string and number format (so I have to parse every variable individually).

Something like this:

`function num(n) { return parseFloat(n) || 0; }`

`var result = (num(width) * num(height)) + num(volume)`

I was thinking it would read better if I could do something like this:

`(width.n() * height.n()) + volumn.n()`

So I was trying to learn more about objects and classes and create a new object type that allows the `n()` method.

This is what I tried:

```
class NumObject extends Object {
  constructor() {
    this.n = function() {
      return num(this);
    }
  }
}
```

But I get this error message in the console:

`Error: |this| used uninitialized in NumObject class constructor`

I'm new to using objects and classes like this, so i'm not sure the proper or best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend another class, you have to first call `super()` in your constructor.

```
class NumObject extends Object {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.n = function() {
      return num(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Either way, there is no need to extend Object, nor to put your methods in the constructor. Just do:

```
class NumObject {
  n() {
   // your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to extend in order to inherit all of the properties of the extended prototype?

Comment: Yes, but there is little point into extending standard Object I think. Usually you want to inherit from another Class.

Comment: Oh ok, is the keyword for that just inherit?

Answer (score 0):

I think `prototyping` is what you are looking for.

```
Object.defineProperty( NumObject.prototype, 'n', {
  value: function(){
    // your logic
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  writable: true
});
```

haven't tested but that should take you in the right direction

If you really want to use inheritance change you code to:

```
class NumObject extends Object {
  n () {
    //...
  }
}
```

note that the whole `constructor(){super()}` is optional all together.